# Programming using Netbeans with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, look-and-feel

Is there a way to a program to be shown like in the Netbeans preview design screen:

[image: previewGUI]

and not like the default running program GUI:

[image]

?

Comment: Use alt+print-screen to capture only the active window.  See also [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots). Also note it is spelled 'Java' as opposed to 'JAVA'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking to set a ["look and feel"](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/LookFeelNative.html)?

Here's the code from the link:

```
// Get the native look and feel class name
String nativeLF = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();

// Install the look and feel
try {
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nativeLF);
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wasn't familiar with that.